# How to create a pandas dataframe from one file (with any file name) located in a specified folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, glob, pathlib

What's the best way to create a pandas dataframe from one file with any file name located in a specified folder?

I have used pathlib and it's not quite working as the output dataframe is not giving me anything.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

pth = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder'
fle = Path(pth).glob('*.tsv')

someDf = pd.DataFrame(fle)
someDf
```

Edit:

I also tried doing the below, but the output dataframe combines all columns into one column separated by a backward slash. How do I fix this?

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

pth = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder'
fle = Path(pth).glob('*.tsv')

dfs = []
for filename in fle:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename))

dfs1 = pd.concat(dfs)
dfs1.head()
```

[image]

The way I did this seems complicated. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Try printing `fle` to see what's in it. You'll need to deal with 0 or more files and will need to use `pandas.read_csv` to read them.

Comment: Thanks. `print(fle)` gives me a generator object. I dealt with the 0 or more files with a loop and used `pd.read_csv`, but the output dataframe combines all columns into one column separated by a backward slash. How do I fix this, or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Oh nevermind, I found the solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found for this is as below. I missed the `sep` parameter in `pd.read_csv()`.

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

pth = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder'
fle = Path(pth).glob('*.tsv')

dfs = []
for filename in fle:
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t'))

dfs1 = pd.concat(dfs)
dfs1.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
import os
pth = r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder'
for file_ in os.listdir(pth):
    h=os.path.join(pth, file_)
    #print (h)
someDf = pd.read_csv(h)
someDf
```

Comment: Thanks. I was able to modify your code to entirely depend on `pathlib` only rather than using `os`, which is a plus!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
from glob import glob
files = glob('C:\Users\HP\Desktop\IBM\New folder\*.tsv')
if len(files) == 1:
    dfs = pd.read_csv(files[0], sep='\t')
else:
    dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t') for file in files])
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this with just one file in the folder so that I don't have to use any loops in my code?